Prisma Property 'X' does not exist on type '{}... despite clearly existing
I am trying to use the Prisma ORM. I have an old project from 2022 that I want to update. Everything worked fine back then but now my legacy code has a super weird typescript error
This is the beginning of my function
    export async function getCategoriesToDecks(deckIds: string[]) {
    
      let categories = await prisma.category.findMany({
        where: {
          deckId: {
            in: deckIds,
          },
        },
        include: {
          categoryQuestionCard: {
            include: {
              questionCard: true,
            },
          },
          categoryAnswerCard: {
            include: {
              answerCard: true,
            },
          },
        },
      });
      let filteredCategories = _.filter(categories, (category) => {
        return category.categoryQuestionCard.length !== 0 && category.categoryAnswerCard.length >= 5;
      });

and when I hover over the (category) in my VsCode IDE it says that the type is
(parameter) category: {
    categoryAnswerCard: ({
        answerCard: {
            id: number;
            answer: string;
            probability: number;
            type: string;
        };
    } & {
        categoryName: string;
        deckId: string;
        answerCardId: number;
        ranking: number;
    })[];
    categoryQuestionCard: ({
        ...;
    } & {
        ...;
    })[];
} & {
    ...;
}

which indicates that typescript is very well able to infer the type of this object. When I try to compile the code I get this error
TSError: ⨯ Unable to compile TypeScript:
src/decks.ts:262:21 - error TS2339: Property 'categoryQuestionCard' does not exist on type '{} & { name: string; deckId: string; }'.

262     return category.categoryQuestionCard.length !== 0 && category.categoryAnswerCard.length >= 5;

This makes no sense to be because clearly the type has the property 'categoryQuestionCard'. I have read the prisma docs and there it says that a call like this is not directly possible
https://www.prisma.io/docs/orm/prisma-client/type-safety/operating-against-partial-structures-of-model-types
which is weird because other questions that refer to this doc page are from 2021, which is before I wrote this code. So it used to work DESPITE this blog page.
I tried the fix that they suggest by adding
const categoryWithCards = Prisma.validator<Prisma.categoryDefaultArgs>()(
   {include: {categoryQuestionCard: true, categoryAnswerCard: true}}
)
   type categoryWithCards = Prisma.categoryGetPayload<typeof categoryWithCards>

above the erroneous code. This did not resolve any issues. All other questions regarding this have been resolved by regenerating the prisma client or restarting Typescript. I have tried these solutions many times without success. Anyone know what might be the problem?
